# How to find $\lim_{n \to \infty} (1-\exp(-t - \ln n))^n$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I'm solving question (c) in this exercise:

> Let $\lambda>0$ and $\left(X_{k}\right)_{k}$ a sequence of i.i.d random variables distributed as an $\mathcal{E}(\lambda)$. We set $M_{n}=\sup \left(X_{1}, \ldots, X_{n}\right)$ and $m_{n}=\inf \left(X_{1}, \ldots, X_{n}\right)$
>
> a. Show that $m_{n}$ is exponentially distributed for any $n \in \mathbb{N}^{*}$. Derive the distribution of $n m_{n}$.
>
> b. Compute the cumulative distribution function, $F_{n},$ of $Z_{n}=\lambda M_{n}-\ln n$.
>
> c. Show that $Z_{n}$ converges in distribution and find the limit distribution.

**My attempt:**

Let $F_1, F_2,F_3,F_4$ be the c.d.f of $m_n, n m_n, M_n, Z_n$ respectively.

a. For all $t>0$, we have

$F_1 (t) = \mathbb P (m_n \le t) = 1- \mathbb P (m_n > t) = 1- (\mathbb P (X_1 > t))^n = 1-(\int_t^\infty \lambda \exp(-\lambda x) \, d x)^n =$ $1- (\exp(-\lambda t))^n = 1 - \exp (-n \lambda t)$.

$F_2 (t) = \mathbb P (n m_n \le t) =\mathbb P (m_n \le t/n) = F_1 (t/n) = 1 - \exp (- \lambda t)$.

b. For all $t>0$, we have

$F_3 (t) = \mathbb P (M_n \le t) = (\mathbb P (X_1 \le t))^n =  (\int_0^t \lambda \exp(-\lambda x) \, d x)^n = (1-\exp(-\lambda t))^n$.

$F_4 (t) = \mathbb P (\lambda M_n -\ln n \le t) = \mathbb P ( M_n  \le \frac{t+\ln n}{\lambda}) = F_3 (\frac{t+\ln n}{\lambda}) = (1-\exp(-t - \ln n))^n$

---

After that, I got stuck at finding the limit $$\lim_{n \to \infty} (1-\exp(-t - \ln n))^n$$

Could you please help me compute this limit? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limit simplifies

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(1-\exp(-t-\ln n)\right)^n = \lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1 - \frac{e^{-t}}{n}\right)^n = e^{-e^{-t}}$$

by $e^x = \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n$